# Google cache has been updated but not the real search results; How come?

Tags: seo, google, domains, html

I updated a page title a couple of weeks ago, and just yesterday I saw the Google cache the updated title. However, in the search results, the old title is still displayed.

This confuses me as I thought first the search results are updated, then the cache.  Can anybody can explain this?

Comment: This had happened with me too.

Comment: JP19: What did you do then? What was the cause?

Answer (score 2):

I have had similar experience, and with me it turned out to be:

1) The google results in my country's version google.co.in were not updated. I think the results on google.com were up to date with the cache. If you are not already on google.com but your country specific version, do check the .com version (on main google page, there would be link go to google.com).

2) Once there was a confusion because I think google cache loads javascripts directly from the website (not cached) and hence I was seeing some instant changes on the cached page. Again I don't remember exactly and this definitely doesn't look like the case with you.

Honestly I didn't bother much as its only a matter of time before the results should be updated - but ya, I was surprised too.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes you have to wait. One thing is getting cached and another one is getting indexed. And the way is showing in the search results is the way your page got indexed, so i would give it sometime, however, Google might be also pulling data from Dmoz or another important source.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=tltp&answer=63756#3) Google help page explains that even after the cached version has been removed it may take up some time to re-crawl the same page in order to reflect the latest changes.